# Uncaught ReferenceError - Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

I have created a small website with a couple of buttons. Each button should call a previously defined JS function. But with every button press I get a ReferenceError stating that the function is not defined.

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: mainLightOn is not defined

Here's the code of my site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Home Cinema Control Center</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #636363;
        }
        p {
            color: #3b3b3b;
            font-size: 4.0em;
        }
        .btn-xlarge {
            padding: 18px 28px;
            font-size: 3.5em;
            line-height: normal;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .box {
            background-color: #fbfbfb;
            margin: 120px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 10px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                  // Add stuff later
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        function mainLightOn() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/1");
        }

        function mainLightOff() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/0");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box" style="width:90%; display:table">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%;">
                    <p>Main Light</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOn()">On</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOff()">Off</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Strangely the error does only occur when I open the website from my server. When I open the html locally on my laptop, the functions are called fine.

Comment: If you're including jQuery why not use it and its AJAX methods? I'm also unable to reproduce the error you're seeing based on the code you posted.

Comment: Did you wrap the functions within `.ready()` handler at `<script>` element when you tried? Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnk http://plnkr.co?

Comment: Works fine on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dp46Lyn1/

Answer (score 2):

Your function definitions are inside the `$().ready(function() {... })` body, so the scope is just that function. Javasript that's executed from HTML elements is executed in the global scope.

There's no need to put those functions inside `$().ready()`. You only need to put code there if it has to wait until the DOM is ready before running. But these functions will only be executed when the user clicks on the elements, which can't happen until the DOM is ready.

Comment: So how do I get the functions out of this (implicit?) ready-body?

Comment: I'm not sure why I thought they were inside a function. I must have been seeing things the other day.

Comment: @Barmar Even if you where say you where seeing things 5 years ago, which you where because they are inside a `ready()` function, this helped me understand why my function embedded in an anchor tag that was inside a `td` tag was giving an `Uncaught ReferenceError`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be reproduced if named functions are within `.ready()` handler, where `this` is set to `document`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Home Cinema Control Center</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #636363;
        }
        p {
            color: #3b3b3b;
            font-size: 4.0em;
        }
        .btn-xlarge {
            padding: 18px 28px;
            font-size: 3.5em;
            line-height: normal;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .box {
            background-color: #fbfbfb;
            margin: 120px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 10px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
        function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
          console.log(theUrl);
        }    

      
        function mainLightOn() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/1");
        }

        function mainLightOff() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/0");
        }
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box" style="width:90%; display:table">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%;">
                    <p>Main Light</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOn()">On</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOff()">Off</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Solution, since it does not appear to be possible to set `this` to other than `document` using `.ready()`, where the `onclick` handler is expecting `this` to be `window`, is to place the named functions outside of `.ready()` handler

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Home Cinema Control Center</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #636363;
        }
        p {
            color: #3b3b3b;
            font-size: 4.0em;
        }
        .btn-xlarge {
            padding: 18px 28px;
            font-size: 3.5em;
            line-height: normal;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .box {
            background-color: #fbfbfb;
            margin: 120px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 10px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function httpGetAsync(theUrl) {
          console.log(theUrl);
        }    

      
        function mainLightOn() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/1");
        }

        function mainLightOff() {
            httpGetAsync("/api/mainlight/0");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box" style="width:90%; display:table">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:40%;">
                    <p>Main Light</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOn()">On</button>
                </td>
                <td style="width:30%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xlarge btn-block" onclick="mainLightOff()">Off</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But that's what I did, isn't it? I have no .ready() handler in my code.

Comment: @Boris _"But that's what I did, isn't it? I have no .ready() handler in my code."_ Can you reproduce at plnkr http://plnkr.co?