# Function cannot be called in $(document).ready(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The questionis more of a debuggin/syntax error rather approach .

I have a function(modal confirmation) defined in an external js file which returns a value as such :

```js
function confirmation(question) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<div></div>').html(question).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Confirmation',
      buttons: {
        "Delete All Items": function() {
          defer.resolve("true"); //this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          defer.resolve("false"); //this text 'false' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        //$(this).remove();
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
      }
    });
}
```

Now when I try to call the function inside the `$(document).ready(function() {`; I get an ***Uncaught Reference Error***.

All the necessary files have been included in calling script. I would like to understand why is this and how i can solve the issue?

Comment: Reference error by its own does not make any sense. Can you open the dev tools and check where exactly that error is thrown.

Comment: This function doesn't return anything and by itself, it creates a documentfragment then throws it away, never adding the element to the dom.

Comment: Is the function called at attribute event  [Uncaught ReferenceError - Function is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668892/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined)? Is `defer` returned from function?

Comment: Is the dynamically created `$("<div></div>")` appended to `document`?

Comment: Yes defer is returned from function and div is appended to doc..basically modal dialogue.  The erroeis indeed as u mentioned @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the missing curly-brace at the end, and assuming your "necessary files" include jquery-ui, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your function.  See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjh42/3bxhpmrx), which does not generate any error.

Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code? It may help if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

References:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  confirmation("What's all this, then?");
});

function confirmation(question) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<div></div>').html(question).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Confirmation',
      buttons: {
        "Delete All Items": function() {
          defer.resolve("true"); //this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          defer.resolve("false"); //this text 'false' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        //$(this).remove();
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
      }
    });
}
```